# Puppeteer browser.newPage() hangs

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm, browser, puppeteer

I am using NodeJS Puppeteer in Kubernetes. However, running `page = await browser.newPage();` did not get the result. Since I have timeInterval to keep renewing ServiceBus lock which leads to wait endless. What is going on for `browser.newPage()`?

Code:

```
try {
    log('Launching browser...');
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--enable-font-antialiasing', '--font-render-hinting=medium'],
        timeout: LOAD_TIMEOUT,
        headless: true
    });

    log('Browser is ready');
    page = await browser.newPage();
    log('Page is ready');
} catch(error) {
    reject(error);
    return;
}
```

Log:

```
Launching browser...
Browser is ready
Renew locked message: xxx message
Renew locked message: xxx message
Renew locked message: xxx message
...
```

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: Hi @GowthamSooryaraj, I just increase hardware resource from Kubernetes then temporarily solve the issue. But sometimes it is still having issue then I am testing Puppeteer-sharp instead.